# how to find linux process uptime in days

Tags: shell, unix, sh

Can any one please let me know how can I find the uptime of a unix process in days?
I am able to get the date time of the process with below command

```
[zdkafadm@toplxkafp005 sa]$ ps -eo pid,lstart,cmd |grep server.properties | grep -v auto | awk 'NR==1;'|awk '{print $3" "$4" " $5" "$6}'
Oct 29 12:47:24 2017
```

Somehow I need the output something like 15 days.

Thanks,
Chandan

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19217/how-to-know-how-long-a-process-has-been-running Or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7870/how-to-check-how-long-a-process-has-been-running help you?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (sticking within shell) is using the 'dateutils' package.  Otherwise perl has some fine date/time modules.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fun solution:

```
ps -o etime= ${pid?} | rev | 
sed -e 's/^/ .sdnoces /' -e 's/:/ ,setunim /' \
    -e 's/:/ ,sruoh /' -e 's/-/ ,syad /' | rev
```